Integrating Autodesk Fusion API with Autodesk Platform Services?
I am trying to use Autodesk Platform Services for design automation of Fusion files. I'd like to be able to view and modify user parameters along with using other features of the Fusion API. Can python scripts using the Fusion API be run using APS? I am just getting started on this project but I am not seeing any examples of this, and some sources have said APS doesn't support this functionality.
Currently I am using some of the basic APS tutorials to get familiar with the code while I prove this project out. I can access my .f3d files and get them stored into a bucket. From here how can I write my python script to access this file and get its design information? ChatGPT is recommending a script using the following format and then executing the script as a work item using APS design automation.
import adsk.core, adsk.fusion, adsk.cam

def run(context):
    app = adsk.core.Application.get()
    design = app.activeProduct
    lengthParam = design.userParameters.itemByName('Length')
    lengthParam.expression = '10 cm'

Will this approach work? Any information or help would be greatly appreciated!

Unfortunately, it's not supported at the moment , but it is something we're looking into. 
Once we have something we'll let people know about it.
